# Extending the tangent bundle of a submanifold to a subbundle of the manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Given an $m$-dimensional smooth manifold $M$, and an $n$-dimensional submanifold $N$, with $n<m$, the tangent bundle of $N$ is a smooth $n$-dimensional subbundle of $TM|_N$.

I'm interested in determining when can $TN$ be extended to a smooth $n$-dimensional subbundle of $TM$.

For any $m\ge 2$, it is easy to construct submanifolds whose tangent bundles can't be extended to subbundles of $TM$ (think of a spiral-like submanifold).

On the other hand, every simply connected closed manifold of dimension $n\ge 2$ with $\chi(M)\ne 0$ does not admit any 1-dimensional subbundle, so tangent bundles of 1-dimensional submanifolds can't be extended.

My question can be summarized as:

1. When can $TN$ be extended to a subbundle of $TM$?
2. For which $m$-dimensional manifolds, no $n$-dimensional submanifolds can have their tangent bundles extended?

Cross posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529145/extending-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-submanifold-to-a-subbundle-of-the-manifold).

Comment: What is motivating your question?  In the co-dimension one case the Euler characteristic gives you an answer.  But in higher co-dimension I don't think there's much going on beyond the tautological: look at the exterior of the manifold and ask if the sub-bundle extends over the manifold (from its definition on the boundary).  This is a classical extension problem.

Comment: There isn't a specific motivation, this question peaked the interest of me and a few of my friends (grad-students), and MSE didn't really help. Regarding your comment - Is there a way to show that when the Euler characteristic is $0$, the manifold admits a $1$-dimensional (or $m-1$) subbundle?

Comment: When a manifold admits a 1-dimensional sub-bundle is handled by the Poincare-Hopf index theorem.  Usually it is written in terms of non-vanishing vector fields, but the answer for 1-dimensional sub-bundles is essentially the same.